# JQuery Date picker Change components

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker, datetimepicker

Hi I am using [this](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) jquery datepicker. Till now it is fine.

Now my problem is by default a dropdown control is used to select years, months.

I want to change them to Input type number. How to do this?

I tried changing inside the jquery ui code but I am unable to sort it out.
I am attaching sample datepicker [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a12dan2n/).
Please help me out to find a way to change year and month to number type
Any help would be appreciated.

```js
$("#date").datepicker({
  changeYear: true,
  changeMonth: true,
  dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
  closeText: "Cancel",
  buttonText: "Select date",
  currentText: "Today",
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="date" style="height:20px;" />
</body>
```

Comment: i have inserted code and fiddle too . u can take a look at it

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32466412/replace-year-dropdown-with-textbox-in-jquery-datepicker)